# matplotlib sharex with colorbar not working

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

[image]I have 2 subplots- 1 scatter and one bar for which I would like a shared x axis. The scatter plot has a color bar. The sharex doesn't seem to work with this as the axis for the two plots do not coincide. 
My code:

```
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios':[13,2]},figsize=(15,12), sharex=True)

df_plotdata.plot(kind='scatter', ax=ax, x='index_cancer', y='index_g', s=df_plotdata['freq1']*50, c=df_plotdata['freq2'], cmap=cmap)

df2.plot(ax=ax2, x='index_cancer', y='freq', kind = 'bar')
```

Comment: I realize the colorbar is the problem. Trying to move the colorbar doesn't seem to work. I also can't seem to be able to get rid of it.

Comment: Sharex means that the axes limits are the same and that the axes are synchronized. It doesn't mean that they lie on top of each other. It all depends on how you create the colorbar. Wouldn't it be great if people were just providing [mcve]s in the questions, which could be copied and changed to easily answer their questions?

Answer (score 11):

Sharex means that the axes limits are the same and that the axes are synchronized. It doesn't mean that they lie on top of each other. It all depends on how you create the colorbar.

The colorbar created by pandas scatterplot is, just like any statndard colorbar in matplotlib, created by taking away part of the space for the axes that it relates to. Hence this axes is smaller than other axes from the grid.

Options you have include:

- **Shrinking the other axes of the grid by the same amount than the scatterplot axes.**
  This can be done by using the position of the first axes and set the position of the second axes accordingly, using `ax.get_position()` and `ax.set_postion()`

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import itertools as it

  xy = list( it.product( range(10), range(10) ) )
  df = pd.DataFrame( xy, columns=['x','y'] )
  df['score'] = np.random.random( 100 )

  kw = {'height_ratios':[13,2]}
  fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,  gridspec_kw=kw, sharex=True)

  df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x',  y='y', c='score', s=100, cmap="PuRd",
            ax=ax, colorbar=True)
  df.groupby("x").mean().plot(kind = 'bar', y='score',ax=ax2, legend=False)

  ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.03,0),loc=3)

  pos = ax.get_position()
  pos2 = ax2.get_position()
  ax2.set_position([pos.x0,pos2.y0,pos.width,pos2.height])

  plt.show()
  ```

[image]

- **Create a grid including an axes for the colorbar.**
  In this case you can create a 4 by 4 grid and add the colorbar to the upper right axes of it. This requires to supply the scatter plot to `fig.colorbar()` and specify an axes for the colorbar to live in,

  ```
  fig.colorbar(ax.collections[0], cax=cax)
  ```

  Then remove the lower right axes, which is not needed (`ax.axis("off")`). You may still share the axes, if that is needed, via `ax2.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, ax2)`.

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import itertools as it


  xy = list( it.product( range(10), range(10) ) )
  df = pd.DataFrame( xy, columns=['x','y'] )
  df['score'] = np.random.random( 100 )

  kw = {'height_ratios':[13,2], "width_ratios":[95,5]}
  fig, ((ax, cax),(ax2,aux)) = plt.subplots(2,2,  gridspec_kw=kw)

  df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x',  y='y', c='score', s=80, cmap="PuRd",
           ax=ax,colorbar=False)
  df.groupby("x").mean().plot(kind = 'bar', y='score',ax=ax2, legend=False)

  fig.colorbar(ax.collections[0], cax=cax, label="score")
  aux.axis("off")
  ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.03,0),loc=3)
  ax2.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, ax2)
  ax.tick_params(axis="x", labelbottom=0)
  ax.set_xlabel("")

  plt.show()
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Based on ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer the two following functions would align the axis:

```py
def align_axis_x(ax, ax_target):
    """Make x-axis of `ax` aligned with `ax_target` in figure"""
    posn_old, posn_target = ax.get_position(), ax_target.get_position()
    ax.set_position([posn_target.x0, posn_old.y0, posn_target.width, posn_old.height])

def align_axis_y(ax, ax_target):
    """Make y-axis of `ax` aligned with `ax_target` in figure"""
    posn_old, posn_target = ax.get_position(), ax_target.get_position()
    ax.set_position([posn_old.x0, posn_target.y0, posn_old.width, posn_target.height])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using Matplotlib toolkits (included in Matplotlib)

I would like to add an alternative to the current answers, which is the use of the function `make_axes_locatable` from Matplotlib toolkits. This optimizes the use of space by default. It makes a big difference if you have a complex subplot configuration with several subplots of this type, for example, using gridspec.

#### Example of use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# create some data
xy = list(it.product(range(16), range(16)))
df = pd.DataFrame(xy, columns=["x", "y"])
df["bubles"] = np.random.random(256)

# create figure and main axis
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = plt.gca()

# create a divider from make_axes_locatable
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

# append a new axis on the bottom whose size is 15% of the size of the main ax
bax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="15%", pad=.05)

# append axis on the right for colourbar (size = 5%)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=.05)

cm = "plasma" # defining colourmap
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm)

# plotting on main axis
p1 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x',  y='y', c='bubles', s=df["bubles"]*200, cmap=cm,
          ax=ax, colorbar=False)

# attaching colourbar to the axis at the right
plt.colorbar(sm, cax=cax)

# plotting on the adjascent axis (bottom)
p2 = df.groupby("x").mean().plot(kind = 'bar', y='bubles',ax=bax, legend=False)

# synchronizing plots on the x-axis
p2.sharex(p1)

# inserting some legend
bax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.03,0),loc=3)

plt.show()
```

The code above result in a figure like this:
[image: Result with make_axes_locatable]

See on the GIF below the effect of `sharex` on the synchronization of both x-axes:

[image: Effect of sharex on the synchronization of the axes]