# How to align the axes of a figure in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure with a `2x2` grid of `plt.Axes` (one of which is actually removed). Axes of the same row (resp. col) share the same y-axis (resp. x-axis) range. For example,

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs[0, 0].imshow(np.zeros((2, 2)))
axs[0, 1].imshow(np.zeros((2, 1)))
axs[1, 0].imshow(np.zeros((1, 2)))
axs[1, 1].remove()
plt.show(block=True)
```

This looks like this:

[image]

I want the axes to be aligned, that is, that points with the same x (resp. y) coordinates in the axes of the same column (resp. row) also share the same x (resp. y) coordinate in the figure. What do I need to change to achieve this?

I tried `sharex='col', sharey='row'` as it seemed to provide a solution in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54473768), but all I got is this change in ticks, not in figure alignment:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to allocate twice as much space for upper plots with [matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic) like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    [
        ['00', '01'],
        ['00', '01'],
        ['10', '11']
    ],
    layout='constrained'
)

ax['00'].imshow(np.zeros((2, 2)))
ax['01'].imshow(np.zeros((2, 1)))
ax['10'].imshow(np.zeros((1, 2)))
ax['11'].remove()

plt.show()
```

Voilà:

[image]

Comment: It is a bit hard to scale, but this is the only solution that works perfectly even when going a little wild, like removing ticks on one figure, adding a y label to the other, aso.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped. It looks like the size ratio of subplots matters in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is fine.  However, if you want slightly better spacing, you can specify the height and width ratios, and use `layout='compressed'`, which is meant for fixed-aspect-ratio axes.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/constrainedlayout_guide.html#grids-of-fixed-aspect-ratio-axes-compressed-layout

Note that you don't need the `remove` command either - just use an empty axes sentinel in `subplot_mosaic`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    [
        ['00', '01'],
        ['10', '.']
    ],
    height_ratios=[2, 1],
    width_ratios=[2, 1],
    layout='compressed',
)

ax['00'].imshow(np.zeros((2, 2)))
ax['01'].imshow(np.zeros((2, 1)))
ax['10'].imshow(np.zeros((1, 2)))[![enter image description here][1]][1]

plt.show()
```

[image]